# Test Suite/Project level assertions on SOAP

Tags: soap, soapui

I have different test suites created in SOAP and i want to add common assertions to test suites level so that i can change/update it easily. 
Any solution on this..? Please help

Comment: Please elaborate the use case with an example.

Comment: @Rao : We have different test steps under test cases which include assertion related with count. But count is not static it keeps on changing with new builds and in that case our assertions fails. So to update those assertions we need to open every test steps (having count related failed assertions) and update the expected value manually. To resolve this issue now we have created/added properties with values at Test Case level and using those properties for script assertions under test steps. So in future if any assertions fails we will update just properties value at Test Case level.

Comment: Would you mind showing the sample assertion code snippet? By the way, are you using Open Source edition or Pro?

Comment: @Rao : I am using Open Source edition.